# Perl one liner to find and replace in a file with a variable

Tags: perl, command-line

I'm trying to find `<li ><a href='xxxxxxxx'>some_link</a></li>` and replace it with nothing. To do this, I'm running the command below but it's recognizing $ as part of a regex.

`perl -p -i -e 's/<li ><a href=.*$SOMEVAR.*li>\n//g' file.html`

I've tried the following things,
`${SOMEVAR}`
`\$SOMEVAR`
`FIND="<li ><a href=.*$SOMEVAR.*li>"; perl -p -i -e 's/$FIND//g' file.html`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for making me look up what the `-i` flag does. That is cool. Pro tip: you can put all the flags together like this: `-pie`

Comment: Also, kudos on a solid first post. Problem described concisely, along with attempted solutions. Well done.

Comment: @Chriszuma have you tried the actual -pie combination?

Comment: Dang, no I hadn't. It seems you can't combine those 3, but you can still do `-i -pe`.

Answer (score 12):

Bash only does variable substitution with double quotes.

This should work:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/<li ><a href=.*?$SOMEVAR.*?li>\n//g" file.html
```

**EDIT** Actually, that might act weird with the `\n` in there. Another approach is to take advantage of Bash's string concatenation. This should work:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/<li ><a href=.*?'$SOMEVAR'.*?li>\n//g' file.html
```

**EDIT 2:** I just took a closer look at what you're trying to do, and it's kind of dangerous. You're using the [greedy](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Greedy) form of `.*`, which could match a lot more text than you want. Use `.*?` instead. I updated the above regexes.

Comment: The order of the switches didn't matter for my case (coming over from `sed -ri` for regex lookaround support), but I had to separate the short-form switches, unless I would get the error `Can't open perl script ...: No such file or directory` for my `-e <code>` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If "SOMEVAR" is truly an external variable, you could export it to the environment and reference it thus:

```
SOMEVAR=whatever perl -p -i -e 's/<li ><a href=.*$ENV{SOMEVAR}.*li>\n//g' file.html
```